# Can't find CreateQuery() method

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, visual-studio-2012, createquery

I'm a new beginner to the entity framework .

and i can't find the following method [CreateQuery()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb339670.aspx)

---

[image]

why i can't find this method ?!!

Comment: You don't need that. If you need to retrieve the `PersonCreditCards` values just do `context.PersonCreditCards.Where(criteria)`. It's called LinQ to Entities. Research on that.

Comment: i want to learn `EntitySQLQuery` too . iwant to use this method :)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Since ESQL was considered an advanced use case, there is no straightforward API from `DbContext`. You can access the `ObjectContext` that backs your `DbContext` to do what you want:

```
((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext.CreateQuery<Person>("esql..")
```

Related: http://thedatafarm.com/blog/data-access/accessing-objectcontext-features-from-ef-4-1-dbcontext/

As suggested there, you can also add a method ( or property) `ObjectContext` to your context class:

```
public class BloggingContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }

    public ObjectContext ObjectContext()
    {
        return (this as IObjectContextAdapter).ObjectContext;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

First of all, this is not the native solution for querying in EF. Please learn as much LINQ as you can and then, if you know you really need alternate methods, fall back to CreateQuery()

But, you can get the result you want with casting to `System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.IObjectContextAdapter` like this:

`(context as IObjectContextAdapter).ObjectContext.CreateQuery`

Also, you can run sql commands with:

`context.Database.SqlQuery<>()` and `context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand()`

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

I am using ef core and I want to get server time from sqlserver and none of the approaches worked in my case. IObjectContextAdapter is not recognized, it asked me to download ef 6.

I have found below statement to get server time:

```
private DateTime GetServerTime()
{
    using (var db = new DbContext())
    {
        DbConnection connection = db.Database.GetDbConnection();
        connection.Open();
        DbCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT GETDATE()";
        return (DateTime)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    }
}
```

You can use this method to create any sql statement and get data from db.
Hope it helps somebody.