# Where is CreateQuery in Entity Framework 6

Tags: frameworks, entity, createquery

Simple question - where is dbContext.CreateQuery method in Entity Framework 6 and if the answer is there is not such method my question is what to do to get some data by SQL query to an objectQuery?

Comment: Check out this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14506161/cant-find-createquery-method

Answer (score 0):

Cast context to `IObjectContextAdapter` and use `ObjectContext`, e.g.:

```
        using (var context = new AdventureEntities())
        {
            string eSql = "SELECT VALUE c FROM AdventureEntities.Customer AS c ORDER BY c.LastName";
            var query = ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext.CreateQuery<Customer>(eSql);
            var customers = query.ToList();
            foreach (Customer customer in customers)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", customer.FirstName, customer.LastName);
            }
        }
```