# How to use ExecuteStoreQuery or CreateQuery in EntityFramework?

Tags: mysql, entity-framework

I tried to use CreateQuery method or ExecuteStoreQuery by refrening the below link

Actually I need to Get the data using MYSQL query but i didn't find any method for that i am trying with the sql method in entity those are also not working, like this how to add MySQL query in Entity Framework?
http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/Querying-with-EDM.aspx

I added both the namespace

```
                    using System.Data.Objects;
                    using System.Data.Entity;
```

still I didn't get  those two methods can any one help me

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since ESQL was considered an advanced use case, there is no straightforward API from DbContext. You can access the ObjectContext that backs your DbContext to do what you want:

```
        ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext.CreateQuery<Person>("esql..")
```

Refer Below Link

[Can't find CreateQuery() method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14506161/cant-find-createquery-method)